# Maya Python: IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, maya

I created a maya python toolchain for my team. All works well, just on one machine i seem to have problems. I narrowed it down to the print command. Like this test library called "temp.py":

```
import os
# from pymel.core import *

print "Hello"
```

after importing it with

```
import temp
```

it produces this output (only on that one computer!):

```
// Error: 9
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# File "C:\maya_scripts\temp.py", line 4, in <module>
# print "Hello"
# IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor //
```

I've tried Maya Version **2016, 2016.5 and 2017**. All the same result. **Python 2.5** as standalone hasn't got that problem. To me that sounds like some kind of configuration problem, but then again it behaves the same over 3 different maya installations, so deleting the prefs didn't help either.

Comment: Are you running a GUI maya or a mayapy.exe standalonw?

Comment: I'm running it in the Maya app itself, i get this error in the maya script editor console.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's really happening here. But try this

```
import sys
sys.__stdout__.write("hello")
 sys.__stdout__.write(str(sys.stdout))
```

Then check your output window (*not* the listener). In a vanilla maya you'd expect to see something like

```
<maya.Output object at 0x00000217E827FC10>
```

after "hello".  If you see something else, some script has tried to hijack `sys.stdout` in this installation.  You can *probably* work around it by creating an environment variable called `MAYA_SKIP_USERSETUP_PY`, setting it to `1`, and restarting -- that should stop whatever script is being naughty from autoloading.

This *ought* to reset it to what you're looking for:

```
 import maya.utils as utils
 sys.stdout = utils.Output()
```

However you need to comb through the scripts on that machine and find out who is messing with `sys.stdout` behind your back

Answer (score -1):

The error is from your module, you may overwrite the print function

maya 2016 is python 2.7.6 and maya 2017 is in python 3.x
on 2017 you must use print("")

Comment: That's not correct: 2017 is 2.7.6:  https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-C0F27A50-3DD6-454C-A4D1-9E3C44B3C990-htm.html

Comment: Yea, i was aware of that. This is a very special case on simply one machine and only when print is used in a library (via import). The same code works on the same app on a different machine. And it fails on that machine on 3 different versions of the same app, while working in a pure python runtime.

It's a very, very puzzling behaviour. My only idea atm is that some script or plugin is changing something in the way stdout is processed by print...

Comment: theodox, you are linking maya 2016 documentation but you right, they just moved to pyside2 and python seems to be 2.7.11 : http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2016/08/compiler-versions-for-maya-2017.html

Comment: is the one machine not working is yours ? maybe a conflict of library

Comment: Okay, i was wrong with the *"only when print is used in a library"*. As it seems print is not working at all. And actually this also produces the same problem:

    sys.stdout.write("hello\n")

Comment: Nope, it's from one of our artists.

And it's stdout, that throws the error. I'm not techie enough to even imagine what that might cause it.

Comment: If this artist has scripts, it may enter in conflict. Have you got some os call ?

Comment: That's my assumption aswell. What do you mean with "os call"?